# ZeroMQ (PHP-ZMQ) pass object via send

Tags: php, queue, zeromq

Is it possible to send object via Socket send in ZeroMQ?

I know in the documentation, it says it only accepts string.

But how would you actually pass objects though? Is there a way around this?

Comment: What kind of object would you like to pass? Can it be text-encoded?

Comment: It's a PHP object retrieved using variety of methods and pulled from database initially. I've tried `sendMulti` and `recvMulti` but they only accept single dimentional Array

Comment: You can't send `byte[]` in php zmq? If so, just serialize the object.

Comment: or encode it in json...

Comment: @mattexx I like your idea better; find a good json library for php and you're good to go.

Comment: I passed it via JSON. But would it process faster (and handle better) on TCP protocol with ZeroMQ for PHP and Mail operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your object is a multi-dimensional array, you can make a json-encoded string:

```
objString = json_encode(obj);
```

Push the string, and decode with your puller:

```
obj = json_decode(obj);
```